# How can I bind datatable to bindingsource as datasource?

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms, datagridview

I have a small winforms powershell gui with a datagridview. The datagridview uses a datatable that get's data from a SQL-Server as the datasource.

Now I wanna implement a filter using the DataGridViewAutoFilter Library which requires me to have the data in a bindingsource. From what I found online I thought that you can just use the datatable as a datasource for the bindingsource like this:

```
#Add assemblies
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms;

$script:stage = 'Prelive';

#region.stage - collects multiple strings like connstring from ext. script
#Skip to function GetAWTagebuch for the actual script
if($script:stage){
    #region0.externeKomponenten
        # SkriptVersion
        $script:version = "0.1.0.5" 

        #"Stage: $script:stage , Quartal: $Quartal, Periode: $Periode, Zeitpunkt: $Zeitpunkt, Periodenconnstring: $PeriodeConnection"  | Out-File -FilePath "\\filegradientprelive\data\Deployment\Auslieferung\Quartalsunabhaengig\KVNO\Powershell_Skripte\BackupActivity\output.txt"
        if($script:stage -eq "Live"){
          $Toolspath = "\\filegradientlive\data\Deployment\Ausfuehrung\Powershell\Tools\Tools.ps1"
        }
        elseif($script:stage -eq "Prelive"){
          $Toolspath = "\\filegradientprelive\data\Deployment\Ausfuehrung\Powershell\Tools\Tools.ps1"
        }

        if (Test-Path $Toolspath) {
            . (Get-Item $Toolspath)
        }
        elseif(Test-Path ((Get-Item -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).DirectoryName + "\Tools.ps1")){
            # Prämisse: Toolsskript liegt im gleichen Scriptverzeichnis
            . ((Get-Item -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).DirectoryName + "\Tools.ps1")    
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "Es konnte kein Tools-Skript eingebunden werden. Das Skript wird beendet."
            echo
            exit
        }
    #endregion0.externeKomponenten

    #region1.GlobaleVariablen
        [string]$script:LogLauf='1'
        [string]$script:stage = $script:stage
        [string]$script:Periode = $Periode

        $script:GrundParam = get-Grundparameter -Stage $script:stage -Periode $Periode -LoggingTabelle $LoggingTabelle

        #Folgende Werte werden als Grundparameter zurückgeliefert
        [string]$script:CS_Systempruefung = $script:GrundParam.CS_Systempruefung;
        [string]$script:CS_Gradient = $script:GrundParam.CS_Gradient;
        [string]$script:CS_KVnet = $script:GrundParam.CS_KVnet;
        [string]$script:CS_Logging = $script:GrundParam.CS_Logging;
        [string]$script:LoggingTabelle = $script:GrundParam.LoggingTabelle;
        [string]$script:LogLaufId = $script:GrundParam.LogLaufId;
        [string]$script:Fileserver = $script:GrundParam.Fileserver;
        [string]$script:Auslieferungspfad = $script:GrundParam.Auslieferungspfad;
        [string]$script:Einzelinstanz_gerade = $script:GrundParam.Einzelinstanz_gerade;
        [string]$script:Einzelinstanz_ungerade = $script:GrundParam.Einzelinstanz_ungerade;
        [string]$script:DWH_Sammelinstanz = $script:GrundParam.DWH_Sammelinstanz;
        [string]$script:Sammelinstanz = $script:GrundParam.Sammelinstanz;
        [string]$script:AkonInstanz = $script:GrundParam.AkonInstanz;
        [string]$script:KVOnlineInstanz = $script:GrundParam.KVOnlineInstanz;

        #Zusätzliche Parametr bei angabe einer Periode
        [string]$script:Periode = $Periode;
        [string]$script:CS_Periode = $script:GrundParam.CS_Periode;
        [string]$script:CS_Workflow  = $script:GrundParam.CS_Workflow;
        #[string]$script:CS_Intermediate = $script:GrundParam.CS_Intermediate;
        [string]$script:PeriodenInstanz = $script:GrundParam.PeriodenInstanz;
        [string]$script:Sammelinstanz_Periode = $script:GrundParam.Sammelinstanz_Periode;
        #[string]$script:IntermediateInstanz = $script:GrundParam.IntermediateInstanz;
        [string]$script:IntermediateDB = $script:GrundParam.IntermediateDB;
        [string]$script:PeriodenId = $script:GrundParam.PeriodenId;
        [string]$script:KVnetTyp = $script:GrundParam.KVnetTyp;
    #endregion1.GlobaleVariablen
}

function GetAWTagebuch {
    $dt = PM_DB-TableResult -Periode $script:stage -SQL ("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[IUP_AWtable];") -ConnectionString $script:CS_Systempruefung -LogConnectionString $script:CS_Logging -LogTable $script:LoggingTabelle -TestName AWtable;
}

function GenerateForm {
    #Form parameters
    $form_dbtest = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
    $form_dbtest.Name = 'Binding Source Test';
    $form_dbtest.Text = 'Binding Source Test';
    $form_dbtest.Size = '1310, 650';
    $form_dbtest.StartPosition = 1;
    $form_dbtest.BackColor = '#3D6387';
    $form_dbtest.FormBorderStyle = 3;

    #Bindingsource
    $BSBindingSource = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource;
    
    #DataTable
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
    GetAWTagebuch

    $BSBindingSource.DataSource = $dt;

    #DGV
    $dgv = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView;
    $dgv.Name = 'dataGridView1';
    $dgv.Size = '1235, 441';
    $dgv.Anchor = (4, 8, 1);
    $dgv.Location = '13, 21';
    $dgv.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = '#000096';
    $dgv.TabIndex = 3;
    $dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 2;
    $dgv.RowHeadersVisible = $True;
    $dgv.RowHeadersWidth = 24;
    $dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = $False;
    $dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $False;
    $dgv.AllowUserToOrderColumns = $True;
    $dgv.DataSource = $BSBindingSource;

    $form_dbtest.Controls.Add($dgv);

    [void]$form_dbtest.ShowDialog();
}

GenerateForm
```

For whatever reason that doesn't work though. I don't get an error but the DGV isn't displaying anything. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/how I do it correctly?

### Edit: Included the whole script. It starts at function GetAWTagebuch. The part before that gets the connectionstring and other strings from an external script

Comment: There is not enough code to reproduce the issue. What you have so far looks good. There is no issue there

Comment: It's not clear how you referenced the DataGridViewAutoFilter package here. To make it work, you have to replace all Columns of Type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` with the provided `DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBoxColumn`

Comment: @Jimi well.. I didn't even get to that part. The issue is that with the code I have the datagridview is just a greybox, not even containing headers. When I use the datatable as datasource for the datagridview it works fine

Comment: You do not need binding source with DataTable and DGV.  You just need $dgv.DataSource = $dt.

Comment: @jdweng I know that. I wanna use `DataGridViewAutoFilter` though which according to the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dependencies) requires me to use a BindingSource. That's the reason why I want one. Maybe wasn't very clear in the question.

Comment: Does DGV show results using $dgv.DataSource = $dt? Use my code to add sample data to see if issue is binding or just the DGV isn't getting displayed.  The link has sample c# code at end of first section (just before contents).  c# code can easily be converted to powershell.  I'll help if you have any questions.

Comment: @jdweng it did but now the bindingsource works too. I changed all variables to include `$script:` because apparently some of them didn't get along with another script. Converting C# to powershell would definetely be useful but I don't know anything about C#. Is there a tool that can do something like that? I know PSProTools but that isn't free anymore.

Comment: Powershell is written in c#.  I do not know of any tools that does conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250285/discussion-between-icoryx-and-jdweng).

Comment: Did you check what `$dt` is before you try to assign it? `GetAWTagebuch` has no return value, the DataTable's Rows are probably *conveniently streamlined* in the pipeline. Try to assign `$dt` directly from the value returned by `GetAWTagebuch` and make this method `return ,$dt;` (the comma is not a typo)

Comment: @Jimi I don't really understand what you mean. `GetAWTagebuch`'s only purpose is to retrieve the newest data from the SQL server and store it in `$dt`. What would be the benefit of returning the data and then assigning it? It's a pretty big amount of data, atleast if you're gonna output it in the console which `return ,$dt` would do afaik. Anyways, after adding `$script` to all the variables it works. Would still like to understand what you mean though as it may help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like you would in c# without binding

```
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$dt.Columns.Add("col1") | Out-Null
$dt.Columns.Add("col2") | Out-Null
$dt.Rows.Add(@("1","2")) | Out-Null

$datagridview.DataSource = $dt
```

Comment: This isn't the issue. I fill the datatable with data from an SQL Query and then want to assign that datatable to the datasource of a bindingsource.